# Darboux's Theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

I read proofs of Darboux's theorem that a symplectic form $\omega$ on M locally is symplectomorphic to a standard symplectic form $\omega_{0}= \sum dp \wedge dq$ in Rolf Berndt's An Introduction to Symplectic Geometry and Arnold's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics.

The treatment of their proofs are quite different. In Rolf Berndt's book, the proof relies on Cartan's magic formula and Poincare's lemma. One can see clearly how closedness and nondegenerancy of symplectic form are used. Arnold's proof, on the other hand, is constructive and geometrical. He showed how to construct hamiltonians that provide local standard coordinates. However, I don't see how closedness condition is involved.

I guess there is some relation between these proofs that are cores none can bypass. Is this right? Can anyone show how to go from one proof to the other?

Comment: I fixed the tags. And by the way, a symplectic form is only _locally_ standard.

Comment: I don't have time right now to match up the proofs, but I think it's worth noting that while Arnold doesn't explicitly discuss closedness, it's implicit in his premise that what he needs is a set of Poisson commuting functions.  So without a closed 2-form, all of Arnold's proof is nonsense.